# Cannot render db data in python flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting started with Python Flask, I am trying to see how I can render data to the html view getting data from database. When I run the code it produces no error but the view has no information, if I try the code in a separate test file, I can see that everything from the database shows up in the console, but not sure why it doesnt show in the html view. 
Here is the code.

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, Restaurant, MenuItem

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = DBSession()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def HelloWorld():
    allRest = session.query(Restaurant).all()
    output = ''
    for el in allRest:
        output += el.id
        output += '</br>'
    return output
```

Html view : Empty and no errors. So I am not sure why cant I see anything after getting all information from the db.

Comment: Is the database filled with data ?

Comment: @SelimAjimi Yes, I added a seed, has alot of information and I can get them working if I just create a test.py file with the same command I used above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the database was created and have data inside. Then you need to convert id's to string explicitly:

```
output += str(el.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most likely answer to this is that there is no data in the database. If that isn't it, we probably need more information. Probably we are going to need to see the html code being output, at least. That said, you should be able to debug this much more easily yourself than someone remotely. I have two recommendations for you:

1. Start using pycharm. With pycharm you can set breakpoints to step through your code. This alone will probably show you where the problem is. For example, you could set a break after retrieving the `Restaurant` objects and simply see whether it has returned anything.
2. Consider using flask-sqlalchemy instead of raw sqlalchemy. This isn't as important as pycharm, but it's helpful.